# Problema Modal con Tailwindcss + Laravel 10 que sobre pone fondo negro

Tags: laravel, modal, tailwind

Estoy insertando un modal con Tailwindcss en mi proyecto en Laravel 10 y al darle al botón para abrir el modal todo sucede como se espera, a excepción del fondo negro que se sobre pone ante todo el contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modal que estoy usando es el "Fullscreen modal" y tomé el código de [aquí](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/modal/)

Mi head está así:

```
    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/icons/fontawesome/css/all.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/animate/animate.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css') }}">  
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/css/tw-elements.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.0"></script>
    <script>
        tailwind.config = {
        darkMode: "class",
        theme: {
            fontFamily: {
            sans: ["Roboto", "sans-serif"],
            body: ["Roboto", "sans-serif"],
            mono: ["ui-monospace", "monospace"],
            },
        },
        corePlugins: {
            preflight: false,
        },
        };
    </script>
```

Y los scripts antes del cierre del body están así:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tw-elements/dist/js/tw-elements.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script><!-- JQUERY MIN JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script><!-- BOOTSTRAP MIN JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js') }}"></script><!-- BOOTSTRAP SELECT MIN JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/counter/waypoints-min.js') }}"></script><!-- WAYPOINTS JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/counter/counterup.min.js') }}"></script><!-- COUNTERUP JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/wow/wow.min.js') }}"></script><!-- WOW JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js') }}"></script><!-- SWIPER JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/tp.carousel.js') }}"></script><!-- tp CAROUSEL JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/tp.ajax.js') }}"></script><!-- AJAX -->
```

De momento lo he solucionado colocando al inicio de la página donde se muestra el modal el siguiente código de estilos para evitar que se vea ese fondo:

```
<style>
    .undefined {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

pero evidentemente es un hardcodeo que no debería estar y estoy casi seguro de que existe una solución definitiva y que vaya directo al problema.